# How make labels for bar names a smaller font size in barplot()?

Tags: r, bar-chart

Using the barplot() function here below:

```
barplot(
norm_clade_counts[[tax_level]][ok,all],
col = mycols(length(ok)),
las = 2,
names.arg = paste(sample_type[all], sample_name[all])
)

legend(
"bottomleft", bty = "n", pch = 19,
col = mycols(length(ok))[1:length(ok)],
cex = 1, inset = c(1,0), 
legend = rownames(clade_counts[[tax_level]])[ok]
)
```

And the barplot I get looks like this, where the names of the bars are not fully visible in the window. How do I change the fontsize of these labels? [image]

Comment: Perhaps you can simply drag your plotting window to make it taller - this will create more room for the labels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can increase the bottom margin by modifying the `mar` (margins) graphical parameter.

```r
# What are the margins currently?
# The `mar` graphical parameter has the form c(bottom, left, top, right)
# These are the number of (fractional) lines on each side of the plot.
default_margins <- par("mar")
default_margins
#> [1] 5.1 4.1 4.1 2.1

# Make the bottom margin larger
new_margins <- default_margins + c(4, 0, 0, 0)
par(mar = new_margins)

barplot(GNP ~ Year, data = longley, las = 2, xlab = "", ylab = "")
```

[image]

```r
# Reset the margins
par(mar = default_margins)
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>